# Query to find tables created in the last hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to find out which tables have been created in the last hour in a MS SQL Server database. How can I do this?

Comment: Try this `select * from sys.tables where create_date >= DATEADD(hh,-1,getdate())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query `sys.tables`.

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    sys.tables AS T
WHERE
    T.create_date >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Will just give you results of the currently connected database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        [name]
       ,create_date
FROM
        sys.tables

WHERE create_date >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to query [sys.tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) catalag view, which inherits column `create_date` from [sys.objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) catalog view.

Statement for the current database:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, create_date, GETDATE()) < 1
```

If you need to get this information for all your databases, generate and execute a dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N''

SELECT @stm = 
    @stm + CONCAT(
            N'UNION ALL SELECT ''', 
            [name] , 
            ''' AS DatabaseName, [name] AS TableName FROM ', 
            QUOTENAME([name]), 
            N'.sys.tables WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, create_date, GETDATE()) < 1 '
    )
FROM sys.databases
SET @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, N'')

EXEC (@stm)
```